# How to save List<UserDefinedClass> of between Activity switching?

Tags: android

How to save `List<UserDefinedClass>` of between Activity switching ? I get data in onClickView function. Does UserDefinedClass need to  implements some interface ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the best way would be to keep the list in the `Application` context.

In any of your activitys call `yourApp` using:

```
((yourApp)getApplication()).//any public function
```

---

```
public yourApp extends Application{
    private List<UserDefinedClass> yourList;

    //create functions to manipulate the list example:
    public void add(UserDefinedClass a){
        //add this to list
    }

    //finally function to access list
    public List<UserDefinedClass> getList(){
        return yourList;
    }
}
```

---

```
//example:
List<UserDefinedClass> aList = ((yourApp)getApplication()).getList();
```

Answer (score 1):

It is best to only pass an identifier to the next Activity instead of passing your entire list.

`UserDefinedClass` should not implement some interface, rather `UserDefinedClass` should be the class type of the List. In other words, every item in your list should be of `UserDefinedClass`. That can be a String or even a custom class.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can pass it if it implements [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html). However if its a large amount of data a database or file may work out better for you.